# Command "wc -l" displays wrong count of lines, possibly because each line starts with a comma?

Tags: csv, gzip, wc

I have a czv.gz file and when issuing "less" command it looks like this

```
COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3
,value1,value2,value3
,value4,value5,value6
...
```

There are thousands of lines in a file but when I issue `wc -l myfile.csv.gz` I get the output something like this:

```
4 myfile.csv.gz
```

I suspect that the comma char at the start of each line is causing this? How could I solve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Causing what? What is the issue? You have shown us a file with 4 lines and `wc` output reporting 4 lines. More importantly, are you running `wc` on a compressed file (`.gz`) file? The comma is irrelevant, in any case.

Comment: It is NOT the initial comma, and it looks like a text file. The filename should be `myfile.csv`

Comment: `wc` certainly doesn't care about commas. `less` may uncompress gzipped files automatically (via the `LESSOPEN` hook), but `wc` does not. Use `zcat -f myfile.csv.gz | wc -l`.

Comment: @terdon says, you show four lines. If your `...` is intended to indicate more lines, then it could be that your (unshown) `less` command is uncompressing the .gz file whereas `wc` is processing the compressed data (and finding only 4 linefeeds)

Comment: Add the output of `file myfile.csv.gz` to the question.

Comment: @waltinator no the file name should **NOT** be changed. File extensions make no difference, but it may provide a clue to the problem.

Comment: You clearly have a compressed file. The newlines in the compressed data are purely accidentally four. `less` knows how to handle compressed data on your system, but `wc` does not. Use `gzip -dc filename.csv.gz | wc -l` instead.